# Segmentation Fault in MAtrix Multiplication

Tags: c++

I am a pretty much beginner in C/C++. I was trying to implement a program to return the value of the n-th Fibonacci number using Matrix Exponentiation.I wrote the following code :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Matrix {
    unsigned long long a_00;
    unsigned long long a_01;
    unsigned long long a_10;
    unsigned long long a_11;
}Matrix;

Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long n);
Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long a_00, unsigned long long a_01,
                    unsigned long long a_10, unsigned long long a_11);
Matrix* mult_matrix(Matrix* A, Matrix* B);      
Matrix* expo_matrix(Matrix* A,unsigned int n);
unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n); 

int main() {

    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;

    unsigned long long result = fib_matrix_expo(n);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}


Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long n) {
    Matrix* ret_matrix = (Matrix*)::operator new (sizeof(Matrix));

    (ret_matrix->a_00) = n;
    (ret_matrix->a_01) = n;
    (ret_matrix->a_10) = n;
    (ret_matrix->a_11) = n;

    return ret_matrix;
}

Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long a_00, unsigned long long a_01,
                    unsigned long long a_10, unsigned long long a_11) {
/*==================================================================================*/
    Matrix* ret_matrix = (Matrix*)::operator new (sizeof(Matrix));

    (ret_matrix->a_00) = a_00;
    (ret_matrix->a_01) = a_01;
    (ret_matrix->a_10) = a_10;
    (ret_matrix->a_11) = a_11;

    return ret_matrix;  

}


Matrix* matrix_mult(Matrix* A, Matrix* B) {
    Matrix* result = (Matrix*)::operator new (sizeof(Matrix));

    (result->a_00) = ((A->a_00) * (B->a_00) + (A->a_01)*(B->a_10));
    (result->a_01) = ((A->a_00) * (B->a_01) + (A->a_01)*(B->a_11));
    (result->a_10) = ((A->a_10) * (B->a_00) + (A->a_11)*(B->a_10));
    (result->a_11) = ((A->a_10) * (B->a_01) + (A->a_11)*(B->a_11));

    return result;
}

Matrix* matrix_expo(Matrix* base_matrix, unsigned int index) {
    Matrix* result;

    if (index == 0) {
        result = init_matrix(1);
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        result = base_matrix;
    }
    else {
        Matrix* temp = matrix_expo(base_matrix,static_cast<unsigned int>(index/2));
        result = matrix_mult( matrix_expo(temp,2), matrix_expo(base_matrix,(index % 2)) );
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n) {

    unsigned long long result = 0;
    Matrix* base = init_matrix(1,1,1,0);
    if (n == 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        base = matrix_expo(base,(n-1));
        result = (base->a_00);
    }
    return result;      
}
```

But this code results in segmentation fault for values >= 3. I am feeling that the problem is with the mult_matrix() function but I am unable to find it. Please help.

EDIT :
The bug causing the overflow has been found but there seems to be other logical errors here as well. In particular the edited code outputs wrong values and the outputs to consecutive inputs like 1 and 2 , 3 and 4, 5 and 6 are same. :(

The edited code :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Matrix {
    unsigned long long a_00;
    unsigned long long a_01;
    unsigned long long a_10;
    unsigned long long a_11;
}Matrix;

Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long n);
Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long a_00, unsigned long long a_01,
                    unsigned long long a_10, unsigned long long a_11);
Matrix* mult_matrix(Matrix* A, Matrix* B);      
Matrix* expo_matrix(Matrix* A,unsigned int n);
unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n); 

int main() {

    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;

    unsigned long long result = fib_matrix_expo(n);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}


Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long n) {
    Matrix* ret_matrix = (Matrix*)::operator new (sizeof(Matrix));

    (ret_matrix->a_00) = n;
    (ret_matrix->a_01) = n;
    (ret_matrix->a_10) = n;
    (ret_matrix->a_11) = n;

    return ret_matrix;
}

Matrix* init_matrix(unsigned long long a_00, unsigned long long a_01,
                    unsigned long long a_10, unsigned long long a_11) {
/*==================================================================================*/
    Matrix* ret_matrix = (Matrix*)::operator new (sizeof(Matrix));

    (ret_matrix->a_00) = a_00;
    (ret_matrix->a_01) = a_01;
    (ret_matrix->a_10) = a_10;
    (ret_matrix->a_11) = a_11;

    return ret_matrix;  

}


Matrix* matrix_mult(Matrix* A, Matrix* B) {
    Matrix* result = (Matrix*)::operator new (sizeof(Matrix));

    (result->a_00) = ((A->a_00) * (B->a_00) + (A->a_01)*(B->a_10));
    (result->a_01) = ((A->a_00) * (B->a_01) + (A->a_01)*(B->a_11));
    (result->a_10) = ((A->a_10) * (B->a_00) + (A->a_11)*(B->a_10));
    (result->a_11) = ((A->a_10) * (B->a_01) + (A->a_11)*(B->a_11));

    return result;
}

Matrix* matrix_expo(Matrix* base_matrix, unsigned int index) {
    Matrix* result;

    if (index == 0) {
        result = init_matrix(1);
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        result = base_matrix;
    }
    else {
        Matrix* temp = matrix_expo(base_matrix,static_cast<unsigned int>(index/2));
        result = matrix_mult(temp,temp);
        result = matrix_mult(result,matrix_expo(base_matrix,(index % 2)));
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n) {

    unsigned long long result = 0;
    Matrix* base = init_matrix(1,1,1,0);
    if (n == 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        base = matrix_expo(base,(n-1));
        result = (base->a_00);
    }
    return result;      
}
```

EDIT : This bug has also been resolved.But as pointed out by Paul this has lots of memory leaks. I shall try to implement this without using manual dynamic memory allocation and repost it. Then as advised by n.m. I  shall update the code after using constructors and removing other unnecessary complex features.The current working code:

EDIT:The code free of memory leaks:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Matrix {
    unsigned long long a_00;
    unsigned long long a_01;
    unsigned long long a_10;
    unsigned long long a_11;
};

Matrix init_matrix(unsigned long long n);
Matrix init_matrix(unsigned long long a_00, unsigned long long a_01,
                   unsigned long long a_10, unsigned long long a_11);
Matrix mult_matrix(const Matrix& A, const Matrix& B);      
Matrix expo_matrix(const Matrix& A,unsigned int n);
unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n); 

int main() {

    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;

    unsigned long long result = fib_matrix_expo(n);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}


Matrix init_matrix(unsigned long long n) {
    Matrix ret_matrix;

    ret_matrix.a_00 = n;
    ret_matrix.a_01 = n;
    ret_matrix.a_10 = n;
    ret_matrix.a_11 = n;

    return ret_matrix;
}

Matrix init_matrix(unsigned long long a_00, unsigned long long a_01,
                    unsigned long long a_10, unsigned long long a_11) {
/*==================================================================================*/
    Matrix ret_matrix;

    ret_matrix.a_00 = a_00;
    ret_matrix.a_01 = a_01;
    ret_matrix.a_10 = a_10;
    ret_matrix.a_11 = a_11;
    return ret_matrix;  
}


Matrix matrix_mult(const Matrix& A, const Matrix& B) {
    Matrix result;

    result.a_00 = ((A.a_00) * (B.a_00) + (A.a_01)*(B.a_10));
    result.a_01 = ((A.a_00) * (B.a_01) + (A.a_01)*(B.a_11));
    result.a_10 = ((A.a_10) * (B.a_00) + (A.a_11)*(B.a_10));
    result.a_11 = ((A.a_10) * (B.a_01) + (A.a_11)*(B.a_11));

    return result;
}

Matrix matrix_expo(const Matrix& base_matrix, unsigned int index) {
    Matrix result;

    if (index == 0) {
        result = init_matrix(1);
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        result = base_matrix;
    }
    else {
        Matrix temp = matrix_expo(base_matrix,static_cast<unsigned int>(index/2));
        result = matrix_mult(temp,temp);
        if(index % 2 == 1) {
            result = matrix_mult(result,base_matrix);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n) {

    unsigned long long result = 0;
    Matrix base = init_matrix(1,1,1,0);
    if (n == 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        base = matrix_expo(base,(n-1));
        result = base.a_00;
    }
    return result;      
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you observe, when you stepped through this code line by line with a decent debugger?

Comment: Pretty bad that I have never had any experience with a debugger. :/ As said I am actually a complete noob in this. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Know how to use a debugger, that's an essential skill. Most IDE's support step by step debugging and setting breakpoints in your code, just out of the box.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal `I am a pretty much beginner in C/C++.`  Which one is it, C or C++?

Comment: OK shall try although I am using linux and gcc. Any debugger for that ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually in both. I just know upto control statements and looping in C++ and just basics of dynamic memory allocation in C.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: good question. The code uses some C++ features but may as well be plain C, as it uses none of C++ higher features.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal - `both`.  Either learn C++ or learn C.  Mixing both of them will just cause confusion as each language has their own way of accomplishing things.

Comment: @Jongware Yes you are correct. It can be pretty much be plian C using printf,scanf and malloc probably.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal - There is no need to dynamically allocate memory in your `init_matrix` function.  Just create one and return by value.  As a matter of fact, there is no need for pointers whatsoever in the code if it's C++.  Maybe passing and returning by reference, but that's it.  Think of `Matrix` just like any other "simple" type, like `int`, `double`, etc., and write your code that way.  You will see that things will start to work correctly.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal - See here: http://ideone.com/N8FyAj  The program there has no memory leaks, as your original code has.  Note how a Matrix is returned just like any other type (no need for dynamic allocation).  However, the code still has the logic bug.  Start with the code posted and try and solve the logic bug (it has to do with infinite recursion in the `matrix_expo` function).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your code. I shall definitely try to find the bug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How does your code output 4930 with no input and output 2 with every input I tried ?

Comment: You are doing several things you need to unlearn, fast: C++-style casts (not needed for this problem), C-style casts (never **ever** use them), dynamic allocation (not needed  for this problem), pointers (not needed  for this problem), `init`-type functions (never use them, use constructors instead), calls to `operator new` (*almost* never do that, learn how to use *new-expression* instead, and that's only when you *need* dynamic allocation; you may need to call `operator new` at some point, but as "pretty much beginner" it's beyond bounds).

Comment: @n.m. Actually I don't yet know about classes and hence I could not use constructors. As for pointers I had the false notion that it is good to use to pointers as it uses memory on the heap. AS for C++ style casts I used them just for the sake of being explicit. And for C style casts and operator new those were The only ways I knew about achieving dynamic memory allocation. Too low experience and lots of bad advices it seems. :(

Comment: No problem. You already have a class, structs are classes, and you can add a constructor to `struct Matrix`.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal - I did not test the code.  What I did was show you how to properly write the code wrt style.  Your original code has memory leaks to the point it is unusable.  The code at the link is a virtual copy of your code, bugs and all *but without the memory leaks*.  That is the first hurdle, and that is make the program correct in that sense.  Now once that's correct, concentrate on the logic bugs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok I shall remove the memory leaks based on your code and then post the updated code here soon. But one question is how do i understand the point of memory leaks ? Valgrind normally shows me no memory leaks but using --leak-check==full shows leaks

Comment: @AbhirupMondal - You used `new`, and not one call to `delete` is made in your code.  You don't need valgrind to show these obvious mistakes.  Your recursion makes this even worse by allocating memory each time the function is called without deallocating the memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually it happened that despite being aware of this thing I was unable to understand how to deallocate after returning the pointer and just hoped to get lucky inspite of knowing that in C/C++ no one gets lucky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stack overflow in the `matrix_expo` function because of recursion here

```
Matrix* temp = matrix_expo(base_matrix,static_cast<unsigned int>(index/2));
result = matrix_mult( matrix_expo(temp,2), matrix_expo(base_matrix,(index % 2)) );
```

lets see why

```
Matrix matrix_expo(Matrix base_matrix, unsigned int index) {
    Matrix result;

    if (index == 0) {
        result = init_matrix(1);
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        result = base_matrix;
    }
    else {
        Matrix temp = matrix_expo(base_matrix,static_cast<unsigned int>(index/2));
        result = matrix_mult( matrix_expo(temp,2), matrix_expo(base_matrix,(index % 2)) );
    }
    return result;
}
```

if `index == 2` then `matrix_expo(temp, 2)` is always reached, and that is causing infinite recursion.

A few other problems are with `new` and never using `delete` and here actually loosing the chance to `delete`

```
base = matrix_expo(base,(n-1));
```

since `base` could be allocated using `new` and you reassing the base pointer which was pointing to `new` allocated memory.

I say could be allocated using `new` because of this line

```
result = base_matrix;
```

here you are returning `base` it self in the case if the previously mentioned case, but in any other case, the other assignments to `result` in this function will allocate using `new` this one will return a pointer to the originally allocated memory, hence if you use the `delete` operator to free this memory, you have a chance to double free.

Comment: Yes you are correct . I just figured it out using gdb. But alas even then there seems to be other logical errors that bugs my code and gives erratic results.Still I am marking this answer correct but please help if you can find out any logical errors in the function. :)

Comment: May be you should ask another question, pointing out what problems you have now. Or if you want to try Jongware's implementation, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ implementation using a *class* for `Matrix`. Unfortunately, I don't know enough of matrices to point out "the" problem with your original code; simply rewriting it with a class seems to have gotten rid of the problem. I couldn't interpret your `expo` function inner workings so I wrote it as a simple loop instead.

Using a class means that all operations are "on" a single Matrix only; no need to make multiple copies anymore! (Except for the `1,1,1,0` helper in the `expo` function; C++ will automatically delete the `temp1` Matrix at the end of that function.)

A new Matrix gets initialized by default with `1,1,1,0`, so the `init` in `expo` and `fib_matrix_expo` can be removed.

This also means you can easily expand the `Matrix` class to perform additional functions.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
    unsigned long long a_00;
    unsigned long long a_01;
    unsigned long long a_10;
    unsigned long long a_11;

public:
    Matrix();
    void init(unsigned long long n);
    void mult(Matrix* B);
    void expo (unsigned int n);
    unsigned long long value ()
    {
        return a_00;
    }
};

unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo(unsigned int n); 

int main() {

    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;

    unsigned long long result = fib_matrix_expo(n);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}

/* In this, and all other class functions, the specifier 'this->' is
   not required. Per definition, all variables from the class are
   immediately accessible. However, including 'this->..' makes it
   clear you *are* modifying the class variables, and not local ones
   with the same name */
Matrix::Matrix () {
    this->a_00 = 1;
    this->a_01 = 1;
    this->a_10 = 1;
    this->a_11 = 0;
}


void Matrix::init (unsigned long long n) {
    this->a_00 = n;
    this->a_01 = n;
    this->a_10 = n;
    this->a_11 = n;
}

void Matrix::mult(Matrix* B)
{
    unsigned long long t00,t01,t10,t11;

    t00 = this->a_00 * B->a_00 + this->a_01 * B->a_10;
    t01 = this->a_00 * B->a_01 + this->a_01 * B->a_11;
    t10 = this->a_10 * B->a_00 + this->a_11 * B->a_10;
    t11 = this->a_10 * B->a_01 + this->a_11 * B->a_11;

    this->a_00 = t00;
    this->a_01 = t01;
    this->a_10 = t10;
    this->a_11 = t11;

    // printf ("%llu %llu %llu %llu\n", a_00, a_01, a_10, a_11);
}

void Matrix::expo(unsigned int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        this->init(1);
        return;
    }
    if (index == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    Matrix temp1;
    // temp1 will initialize itself with (1,1,1,0),
    // nothing more needed
    while (--index > 0)
    {
        this->mult (&temp1);
    }
}

unsigned long long fib_matrix_expo (unsigned int n)
{
    Matrix base;
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    // No need to initialize to the default values, as this
    // is done in the default constructor.
    base.expo(n-1);
    return base.value();
    // Since 'base' is a locally created class object, you
    // do not need to delete it.
}
```

<sup>Constructive criticism is welcomed, as I'm not a daily C++ programmer ;)</sup>

Comment: @iharob: do you think `mult` should be `void mult(Matrix B)`, only to avoid that one `&`?

Comment: There is a typo in your code in line 97. Other than that your code compiles and runs well. But actually I was trying to get an O(log(n)) based implementation to find the n(th)fibonacci number. So i wanted to implement the multiplication using Fast Exponentiation algorithm.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal: iharob spotted that and my code was correct, so it must have been Auto-Correct jumping in! Unfortunately, I don't understand your Fast Expo method so I could not implement it here. Perhaps you can try yourself, as the base of my code seems sound.